# NSUserDefault exists -iPHONE SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa, xcode, nsuserdefaults

How would I check in a "if" statement if the NSUserDefault object is saved there or not? I'm not really sure how to call it.. So a pretty short question..

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Foo"] != nil) {
  NSLog(@"an object is saved under \"Foo\"!");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Dave's answer is correct, but I'd skip the explicit test for nil:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Foo"]) {
    NSLog(@"An object is saved under \"Foo\"!");
}
```

Comment: It's a style choice.  I like to be explicit in my comparisons :)

Comment: @Dave DeLong: Absolutely. Mine is a style choice as well, just pointing out an alternative. Consistency is more important. :)